# Terminal Actived Push Notification Utility for OS X and iOS?

Tags: macos, ios, ssh, notifications

I am basically wondering if there is any tool(s) that can generate a push notifications on OS X and/or iOS from terminal entries. Idea here is you could connect via SSH and make a custom push notification like "WiFi is turning off in 5 Minutes" or "Go to bed!" (lol) appear. Anyone have ideas? My iOS device is jailbroken, hence OpenSSH is installed.

Answer (score 1):

OS X Server integrates nicely for push notifications using APNS, but it's more focused on mail and chat notifications as opposed to sending generic notifications like a turn based game server.

It would get your Apple ID approved and be a very nice first step towards getting APNS to be ready to listen to commands from a Mac.

Here is a nice step by step article on setting up push notifications:

- http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/enable-push-notifications-in-os-x-mountain-lion-server/

From there, you could use a chat hosted from your Mac as opposed to using iMessage (messages app on iOS to get messages sent with push notifications).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind a small one-time entry fee ($5) then there are two apps for iOS that provide you with push notifications.

[Push4](http://www.appnotifications.com/)

[Pushover](https://pushover.net/)

Both provide a simple http API so you can send yourself push notifications from the terminal. Pushover also has IFTTT channel.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nomad/houston

It supports simple command line interface too. Very useful and free.